# Why is the L1-norm in lasso not differentiable?

Tags: regression, logistic, regularization, elastic-net

can someone show that $||w_{1}||$ is not differentiable?

This is based on a claim made in this paper:

http://jmlr.org/papers/volume13/yuan12a/yuan12a.pdf

Comment: Please edit your question to make it still make sense if that link is moved (as happens sometimes, even with journals). That is, your question should stand alone -- in which case you should define your notation, and give a proper reference.

Comment: you probably like to see this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04985

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The L1 norm is $$||w||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |w_i|$$ consider the simple case of a one dimensional $w$, then the L1 norm is simply the absolute value. The absolute value is not differentiable at the origin because it has a "kink" (the derivative from the left does not equal the derivative from the right).

Comment: Just to be a little finicky, it's not differentiable at the value 'zero', everywhere else it is diffentiable.

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: What practical problems can arise from the fact that L1 is not differentiable at the origin?

Comment: @mrgloom it creates difficulties in optimization (ie trying to find max/min value of a function) you lose a lot of nice guaranteed properties for standard optimization techniques. In simplest case where you are trying to optimize absolute value function with gradient descent with fixed step size, the solutions will oscilliate around the minimum without approaching it.